# Pointer subtraction on Big/Little endian

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

This is a sample program to find the length of string.

```
    {
      char *ptr="Autobiography Of Yogi";
      char *a = ptr , *b = &ptr[20];
      printf(" length is %d ", (b-a)+1 ); // subtracting pointers to find string length 
    }
```

My question is , is this program   fine for both Little and Big endian machine ?

Comment: The endianness has no influence on your code. But your code is poor anyway because of the hardcoded `20`.

Comment: Note: pointer subtraction results in type `ptrdiff_t` which may differ from `int`.  Portable C99 code uses `printf("%td\n", (b-a)+1 );`

Comment: The main problem with your approach is rather that in order to use it, you must already know the string length... and it is 21, not 20.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine. Problems appear only when you look at individual bytes of a larger integer.

Comment: @Govind Parmar Thanks for your edit, but I rolled it back because I think it could cause confusion if it says "data type larger than one byte", because for example a string is larger than one byte, yet the endianness does not matter. Endianness really only matters for integers (and somtimes floating point types).

Answer (score 2):

1. You are dealing with characters, so little endian or big endian does not come into the picture. It is only valid for 2 or more byte data values.
2. Subtraction of pointers does not depend on Little endian or big endian anyway.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Individual bytes are not sensitive to endianness

Comment: He is subtracting character pointers. Even if he is subtracting int pointers, the result will be the same regardless of the endianness. That is what I was explaining here.